# How to get the window state of a C++ console application

Tags: console-application

I'm writing a console app in C++ but can't seem to find how to figure out the console window state (i.e. normal, minimized, etc.).  Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows use `GetConsoleWindow` to get a handle to the window, then e.g. `GetWindowPlacement`.

But what on Earth are you planning to use this information for?

Comment: I need the console application to automatically minimize after X seconds goes by if in normal window state.  So if console app becomes un-minimized then it'll wait X second until minimizing again.  Basically this app needs to run silently in the task bar unless someone chooses to show it.